# Script to activate and enter details in System Dialog

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to write a script which can enter details in the system dialog. But i am not able to access it. Is there a way to access this? I tried getting the list of all the system dialogs and alerts but still I am not able to catch this.

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
  get name of every application process ¬
    whose role description of window 1 is "system dialog"
```

[system dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9RdE.png)

Comment: So I can cause that system dialog to appear, what did you do to prompt that system dialog?

Comment: I was trying to run application on my device using Xcode

Comment: Can you please be more explicit and specific so I can replicate having the system dialog appear so I can see how it needs to be coded?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. So I created an ios application using Xcode and I want to run it on my iphone. i am getting this pop up just before the app is installed on my device.

Comment: Okay, thanks, however I'm not in a position to do the same to trigger that dialog. That said, since you have **Xcode**, did you use **Accessibility Inspector** to determine its role was "system dialog"?

Comment: Thanks for the lead. With the help of Roberts Answer and your comment I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure following is what you asked for, but try yourself:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SecurityAgent"
    return name of every window
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "SecurityAgent"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
tell process "SecurityAgent"
    set value of text field 1 of window 1 to "Username"
    set value of text field 2 of window 1 to "Password"
    click button "Allow" of window 1
end tell
end tell
```